# EntityStoreSchemaGenerator is slow

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I've been trying to reverse engineer an empty SQL 2012 database to code. I took the code from the entity framework power tools to reverse engineer. I've noticed when I run the power tools, or run the code below it takes over 2 hours to generate the store schema.

Is there something wrong with the database or is it just inherently slow?

```
EntityStoreSchemaGenerator entityStoreSchemaGenerator = new EntityStoreSchemaGenerator(provider, "Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=InSysV5;Integrated Security=True", "dbo")
            {
                GenerateForeignKeyProperties = true
            };

            entityStoreSchemaGenerator.GenerateForeignKeyProperties = true;
            var filter1 = new EntityStoreSchemaFilterEntry(null, null, null, EntityStoreSchemaFilterObjectTypes.Table, EntityStoreSchemaFilterEffect.Allow);
            var filter2 = new EntityStoreSchemaFilterEntry(null, null, null, EntityStoreSchemaFilterObjectTypes.View, EntityStoreSchemaFilterEffect.Exclude);
            var filter3 = new EntityStoreSchemaFilterEntry(null, null, null, EntityStoreSchemaFilterObjectTypes.Function, EntityStoreSchemaFilterEffect.Exclude);
            var filters = new EntityStoreSchemaFilterEntry[] { filter1, filter2, filter3 };
            var errors1 = entityStoreSchemaGenerator.GenerateStoreMetadata(filters);
```